# How to change default username field after login

Tags: users, login, wp-login-form, username

if i go back to login page after logging in the username is shown in the username/email field(like the image bellow)
[image]

how can i set it to empty or the user email?

Comment: It looks like your theme might actually be filling out the form (if I understand correctly that the "E-mail" field is pre-filled with "username".) Have you tried giving its source code a look?

Comment: are you sure this isn't your browser trying to be helpful?